# Is it better to use "static member" in circular linked list or just go by iterative way?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Code I made for circular linked list:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node
{
  public:
  int data;
  node* next;
  node():data(0),next(NULL){}
  node(int x):data(x),next(NULL){}
};
void push(node** head_ref,int val);
void printlist(node* n);
int main()
{
  node* head=NULL;
  push(&head,14);
  push(&head,24);
  push(&head,67);
  push(&head,77);
  printlist(head);
  return 0;
}
void push(node** head_ref,int val)
{
  node* new_node=new node(val);
  static node* temp_head=NULL;
  if(*head_ref==NULL)
  {
     temp_head=new_node;
     *head_ref=new_node;
     new_node->next=*head_ref;
  }
  else
  {
     new_node->next=*head_ref;
     temp_head->next=new_node;
     *head_ref=new_node;
  } 
}
void printlist(node* n)
{
   node* head_ref=n;
   while(n!=NULL)
   {
      cout<<n->data<<" ";
      if(n->next!=head_ref){n=n->next;}
      else if (n->next==head_ref){break;}
   }
}
```

I was trying to write a code for circular linked list.
I have used **static node*** in **void push()** is it good method or to go by iterative approach
by using while-for loop?

Comment: Can you explain the reason you used a static variable? "Is it better" is pretty opinion-based, but perhaps if you can explain why you did it instead of an alternative way we can talk about that.

Comment: It’s not a “static member”, it is a variable with [“static storage duration”](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration). Regardless, consider what happens when pushing to two different lists at the same time.

Comment: You encapsulte nothing, hence you need hacks to keep state. If you had an actual `list` class, it could hold a pointer to the head *and* the end. No static state needed.

Comment: Whether or not a variable should be static depends on its function. Could you add an explanation of the role fulfilled by `temp_head` in your code? Explicitly writing such things out tends to result in better communication than hoping others see the same things in your code that you do. (The first thing I noticed is that the variable has "temp" in its name, implying that the variable is for temporary storage. A `static` variable implements permanent storage. The name and the `static` qualifier seem to be at odds with each other. Was this something you saw? If not, write out what you mean!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all regarding the static variable it is a pretty good hack to keep the last node (i think you were intending to do that when you started to implement the code). But a quick remark your circular linked list will be reversed in this case because by the idea of the linked list you should add your nodes to the end of the list and not the front(you did just that). I would definitely qualify the code as good if you would have told me this is a code for a reverse linked list.
This is pseudocode for your push function

```
node* new_node=new node(val);
static node* temp_head=nullptr;
if(*head_ref==nullptr)
  {
     temp_head=new_node;
     *head_ref=new_node;
     new_node->next=*head_ref;
  }
else 
{
     temp_head->next = new_node;
     temp_head = temp_head->next;
     temp_head->next = *head_ref;
}
```

But please look at some other implementations of a circular linked list because this one can't be mark approved. You should have a class CircularLinkedList which will carry on all the action like push or print.